# MongoDB Use logical OR in group stage

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a MongoDB collection which looks like this:

```json
{user: "1", likes: 111, isEnabled: true},
{user: "1", likes: 222, isEnabled: false},
{user: "2", likes: 333, isEnabled: false},
{user: "2", likes: 444, isEnabled: false},
```

I want to sum group the them up by the user, sum up the likes and check if one of the documents of a user has "isEnabled" = true (basically a logical OR).

I want this result at the end:

```
{user: "1", allLikes: "333", isAnyEnabled: true},
{user: "2", allLikes: "777", isAnyEnabled: false},
```

I can use the `$sum` accumulator of the `group` stage to sum up the likes. My problem is that there seems to be no `group` operator which supports logical operations on booleans. Is there any way to do this?

I tried this so far

```
db.myCollection.aggregate([{$match: {
    "_id":"$user",
    "allLikes": {
      "$sum": "$likes"
    },
    "isAnyEnabled":{"$or":"$isEnabled"}
}}])
```

But it seems that `$or` is not supported for this: `unknown group operator '$or'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`$anyElementTrue`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/anyElementTrue/) in a project stage like this:

- First `$group` by `_id` to get all likes sumed and a list of all `isEnabled` values
- Then use `$anyElementTrue` to check if there is at least one `true` and then `isAnyEnabled` is true or false.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$user",
      "allLikes": {
        "$sum": "$likes"
      },
      "enabled": {
        "$push": "$isEnabled"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": "$_id",
      "allLikes": "$allLikes",
      "isAnyEnabled": {
        "$anyElementTrue": [
          "$enabled"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/1mcme_LUhTB)